# How to convert password in original format encrypted by cakephp using core php?

Tags: cakephp

i have tried md5(),sha1() in mysql database but don't get original format.i am creating web service for user login system so that in database password have quite different format so how can i figure out it?

Comment: Where is your example code?

Comment: i have complete cakephp web application and all set up database very well but right now i want all username and password which stored in mysql database. i got all data except password because it is quite dffferent in can decrypt only in cakephp but at this time i am working with only mysql database plz tell me ASAP.. Thanks...

Comment: There is no decrypting a password as it's a one-way _hash_. If you mean how to hash a password outside a CakePHP application and get the same hash, the standard hash is a salted sha1 for CakePHP < 3.0 - check the docs or the Auth component code.